# Can I tell my web browser to only display images on white-listed websites or pages?

Tags: firefox, images

I hate pictures on 99% of websites. Can I set Firefox to never display pictures except on websites that I approve?

I mean pictures specifically related to content. Things like formatting or the website's logo are fine. I just don't want to see pictures on the main pages of a trending article, wiki-how page or the like unless I whitelist the site.

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible with an add-on, as Firefox has no such standard method.

Here are some add-ons that are highly noted in the Store:

- [Fast Image Blocker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-blocker-plus/?src=search)
- [Easy Image Blocker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-image-blocker/)
- [Image Block](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-block/)

Comment: I will follow up on Image Block. Its name is the most straightforward.

Comment: The list is in descending note value, and this is the last entry...

Comment: If my answer has helped with the problem, please accept it.